# Login loop problem

Tags: system

Ubuntu 16.04 was working all fine yesterday today when I tried to login to desktop I stucked in loop login
I checkex other solotions nothing helpt me
But I noticed that when I boot in ubuntu thebloading screen of ubuntu is not showing its like going to login window from boot screen directly

Comment: Please describe what other solutions you already tried. Otherwise we will probably advise you to do the same again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I tried this mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak and reconfuguration invidia vedio card

Comment: Please look at the duplicate question I linked you. There are a lot more suggestions what you can try to solve login loops.

Comment: Some configuration issues on X clients can explain this. Maybe try to move all your configuration files to a subdirectory of your home (to keep a backup). Then, without configuration file, try to login.

Answer (score 0):

Some configuration issues on X clients can explain this.

Maybe try to move all your configuration files to a subdirectory of your home (to keep a backup). Then, without configuration file, try to login.

It that works, you'll have to restore one by one your conffigurations in order to identify what makes problem.

Note that to make those operations, you'll have to use virtual console [Ctrl]-[Alt]-[F1] for example.